# Clarification on Cloud Computing Database

Tags: data-synchronization, cloud

This question can be very generic, but I am trying to understand the concept of Cloud Databases.

Let's say I have a Web Application, a Desktop Application, and Apps for my Web Application.

All of my Apps, Web, and Desktop applications communicate with the Database when it is online.

My question is, if there is a situation to work offline, can I work offline on the Desktop App and later sync with Cloud Database?

Just like Dropbox, we can add files to the Dropbox in an offline mode.When Dropbox goes online, Folder will get sync automatically and update all the systems like iPhone - App or other Computer Dropbox folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you cannot work offline and then sync your changes. But this is a nice idea for a product! :)

Comment: Please dont steal my idea, buddy !!

Comment: I am not sure, whether you heard of Smartclient Applications (.Net Platform) which is actually a Desktop Application but it has a Cache Database. Whatever data entered it goes to Local Cache DB (Dataset in .Net ) and then it goes to SQL Database.